How to check if any of buttons is clicked in Qt
I have two buttons: zeroButton and oneButton I create a list of them and want to display "click" on a label when one of buttons is clicked. Im trying to check if one of them is clicked by contains() and mb its not necessary (without it its also doesn't work) but I cast qobject into qpushbutton with qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender())
I tried this:
QList<QPushButton*> *buttons = new QList<QPushButton*>();
    buttons->append(ui->zeroButton);
    buttons->append(ui->oneButton);
    
    if(buttons->contains(qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender()))))
    {
        ui->labelAnswer->setText("click");
    }

but its don't work.
I expect that labelAnswer will be changed on "click"
mainwindow.h:
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QList>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

 private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

mainwindow.cpp:
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QList<QPushButton*> *buttons = new QList<QPushButton*>();
    buttons->append(ui->zeroButton);
    buttons->append(ui->oneButton);

    if(buttons->contains(sender()))
    {
        //QObject *object = new QObject(sender());
        ui->labelAnswer->setText("click");
        //delete object;
        //object = nullptr;
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

main.cpp:
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

mainwindow.ui:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="enabled">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>180</width>
    <height>272</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>180</width>
    <height>272</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>180</width>
    <height>272</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="labelAnswer">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>141</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="autoFillBackground">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>cum</string>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignmentFlag::AlignRight|Qt::AlignmentFlag::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignmentFlag::AlignVCenter</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="clearButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>120</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>C</string>
    </property>
    <attribute name="buttonGroup">
     <string notr="true">buttonGroup</string>
    </attribute>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="oneButton">
    <property name="enabled">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>50</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>1</string>
    </property>
    <attribute name="buttonGroup">
     <string notr="true">buttonGroup</string>
    </attribute>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="twoButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>70</x>
      <y>50</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>2</string>
    </property>
    <attribute name="buttonGroup">
     <string notr="true">buttonGroup</string>
    </attribute>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="threeButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>120</x>
      <y>50</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>3</string>
    </property>
    <attribute name="buttonGroup">
     <string notr="true">buttonGroup</string>
    </attribute>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="plusButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>70</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>+</string>
    </property>
    <attribute name="buttonGroup">
     <string notr="true">buttonGroup</string>
    </attribute>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="fourButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>90</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>4</string>
    </property>
    <attribute name="buttonGroup">
     <string notr="true">buttonGroup</string>
    </attribute>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="fiveButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>70</x>
      <y>90</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>5</string>
    </property>
    <attribute name="buttonGroup">
     <string notr="true">buttonGroup</string>
    </attribute>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="sixButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>121</x>
      <y>90</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>6</string>
    </property>
    <attribute name="buttonGroup">
     <string notr="true">buttonGroup</string>
    </attribute>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="sevenButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>130</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>7</string>
    </property>
    <attribute name="buttonGroup">
     <string notr="true">buttonGroup</string>
    </attribute>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="eightButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>70</x>
      <y>130</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>8</string>
    </property>
    <attribute name="buttonGroup">
     <string notr="true">buttonGroup</string>
    </attribute>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="nineButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>120</x>
      <y>130</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>9</string>
    </property>
    <attribute name="buttonGroup">
     <string notr="true">buttonGroup</string>
    </attribute>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="zeroButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>0</string>
    </property>
    <attribute name="buttonGroup">
     <string notr="true">buttonGroup</string>
    </attribute>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>180</width>
     <height>24</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
 <buttongroups>
  <buttongroup name="buttonGroup"/>
 </buttongroups>
</ui>


Checking the buttons in the constructor doesn't make any sense, at that point the UI hasn't even been shown and that function block will have already returned when the user eventually clicks the buttons. That should be done in a function when a button is clicked, not before. It seems you need to do some research about Qt signals and slots, but also event driven programming and their execution flow.

how can I avoid tons of code and make a single signal to a single slot (like don't write a connect for every button)

You could use QList<QPushButton *> allPButtons = findChildren<QPushButton *>(); then connect each item in the list to a single slot using a for loop.

@Alexey Either use findChildren() as shown above (possibly by calling it for the widget that actually contains those buttons, in order to restrict the search within specific buttons), or eventually use a button group in Designer and iterate through its buttons(), so you don't even need to create a list on your own.

ok ill try thank u all :)

@Alexey "how can I avoid tons of code and make a single signal to a single slot" -- This makes more sense as a question then what you have in your question. Currently, your question is confusing, as if you expect people to know what you are doing without telling them what you are doing. This approach sometimes works when your code is correct, but rarely when it is not... Maybe try adding a walkthrough of what you believe should happen when someone clicks a button.

You can use QButtonGroup as mentioned above, here is an example:
QPushButton b1("1");
QPushButton b2("2");
QButtonGroup g;
b1.show();
b2.show();
g.addButton(&b1,1);
g.addButton(&b2,2);
QObject::connect(&g, &QButtonGroup::idClicked, [](int id){
    qDebug()<<QString("%1 clicked").arg(id);
});

